# Update `div` With Response from MySQL Using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a background process that is aggregating information for me, and I would like to make it so that the web page refreshes the containing `div` every 10 seconds. Unfortunatley, most of the articles I am coming across are for using JS and/or ajax with forms.

I'm trying to do something more along the lines of...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        check_articles("new_articles()", 10000);
    });

    function new_articles(){ 
        document.getElementById("articles").innerHTML="
        <?php  
            $this->select_articles();
        ?>"; 
    } 
</script> 

<div id="articles" onload="check_articles(); return false;">
    Article's contents.
</div>
```

I really need to find the time to brush up on my JS... Anyway, the concept is there. The question is, is there a better (more effective / efficient) way to do this?

I've been up for nearly 24 hours so I'm going to play with this more tomorrow. Nonetheless, I look forward to hearing your guy's feedback and insight, as always.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the `check_articles` function? How does it work?

Comment: You need to do this with Ajax.

Comment: @matewka: `check_articles` is the function referenced in the anonymous closure. Cleary, I don't write a lot of JS from scratch (I tried to make it so it didn't look like pseudo-code, lol). Anyway, I just got the Views straightened out enough to start playing around with this part, but I need to get some sleep before I dive deep. I'd appreciate any insight you might have.

Comment: Its not possible to call a php function from js. you need to make ajax call for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an ajax call  to the server script on regular interval (1000 milli seconds)

```
function callServer(){
 setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "server.php/select_articles",
     success:function(reponse) {
         $("#articles").html(response);
     }
   });
 },1000);
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Excellent, simple enough. I'll start playing around with it now. Thanks, dreamweiver.